# Image Encryption using AES-128

Tags: python, encryption

firstly i made AES-128 program it just encrypt single file with .txt format. and i print the result with matriks 4x4. the code look like this (only function)

```
    def addRoundKey(plain,key):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            plain[i][j]=plain[i][j]^key[i][j]
    return plain
def subByte(plain):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            plain[i][j]=Sbox[plain[i][j]]
    return plain    
def shiftRow(plain):
    plain[0][1],plain[1][1],plain[2][1],plain[3][1]=plain[1][1],plain[2][1],plain[3][1],plain[0][1]
    plain[0][2],plain[1][2],plain[2][2],plain[3][2]=plain[2][2],plain[3][2],plain[0][2],plain[1][2]
    plain[0][3],plain[1][3],plain[2][3],plain[3][3]=plain[3][3],plain[0][3],plain[1][3],plain[2][3]
    return plain
def siapkanMatrixKosong():
    keluaran=[]
    for i in range(4):
        sub=[]
        for j in range(4):
            sub.append(0)
        keluaran.append(sub)
    return keluaran
def mixColumn(plain):
    keluaran=siapkanMatrixKosong()
    keluaran[0][0]=mul2[plain[0][0]]^mul3[plain[0][1]]^plain[0][2]^plain[0][3]
    keluaran[1][0]=mul2[plain[1][0]]^mul3[plain[1][1]]^plain[1][2]^plain[1][3]
    keluaran[2][0]=mul2[plain[2][0]]^mul3[plain[2][1]]^plain[2][2]^plain[2][3]
    keluaran[3][0]=mul2[plain[3][0]]^mul3[plain[3][1]]^plain[3][2]^plain[3][3]
    keluaran[0][1]=plain[0][0]^mul2[plain[0][1]]^mul3[plain[0][2]]^plain[0][3]
    keluaran[1][1]=plain[1][0]^mul2[plain[1][1]]^mul3[plain[1][2]]^plain[1][3]
    keluaran[2][1]=plain[2][0]^mul2[plain[2][1]]^mul3[plain[2][2]]^plain[2][3]
    keluaran[3][1]=plain[3][0]^mul2[plain[3][1]]^mul3[plain[3][2]]^plain[3][3]
    keluaran[0][2]=plain[0][0]^plain[0][1]^mul2[plain[0][2]]^mul3[plain[0][3]]
    keluaran[1][2]=plain[1][0]^plain[1][1]^mul2[plain[1][2]]^mul3[plain[1][3]]
    keluaran[2][2]=plain[2][0]^plain[2][1]^mul2[plain[2][2]]^mul3[plain[2][3]]
    keluaran[3][2]=plain[3][0]^plain[3][1]^mul2[plain[3][2]]^mul3[plain[3][3]]
    keluaran[0][3]=mul3[plain[0][0]]^plain[0][1]^plain[0][2]^mul2[plain[0][3]]
    keluaran[1][3]=mul3[plain[1][0]]^plain[1][1]^plain[1][2]^mul2[plain[1][3]]
    keluaran[2][3]=mul3[plain[2][0]]^plain[2][1]^plain[2][2]^mul2[plain[2][3]]
    keluaran[3][3]=mul3[plain[3][0]]^plain[3][1]^plain[3][2]^mul2[plain[3][3]] 
    return keluaran
def enkripsi(plain,key):
    subkey=keyschedule(key)
    #print('nilai awal :')
    cetak(plain)
    plain=addRoundKey(plain,subkey[0])
    #print('setelah addRoundKey')
    cetak(plain)
    for i in range(9):
        plain=subByte(plain)
       # print('setelah subByte')
        cetak(plain)
        plain=shiftRow(plain)
        #print('setelah shiftRow')
        cetak(plain)
        plain=mixColumn(plain)
        #print('setelah mixColumn')
        cetak(plain)
        plain=addRoundKey(plain,subkey[i+1])
        #print('setelah addRoundKey',i) 
        cetak(plain)
        #print('subkey yang dipakai',i)
        cetak(subkey[i+1]) 
    plain=subByte(plain)
    plain=shiftRow(plain)
    plain=addRoundKey(plain,subkey[10])
    return plain 
#plain=[0x32,0x43,0xf6,0xa8,0x88,0x5a,0x30,0x8d,0x31,0x31,0x98,0xa2,0xe0,0x37,0x07,0x34]
#plain=toTable(plain)


#plain = enkripsi(plain,cipherKey)
#cetak(plain)
def getNextInput(fileDibaca):
    hasil=fileDibaca.read(16)
    panjangFile=len(hasil)
    if(panjangFile<16):
        hasil=hasil.decode()
        for i in range(16-panjangFile):
            hasil=hasil+" "
        hasil=hasil.encode()
    return hasil
def putNextInput(yangDitulis,fileDitulis):
    string=""
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            string+=chr(yangDitulis[i][j])
    string=string.encode().strip()
    fileDitulis.write(string)
    pass
def enkripsiAes():
    try:
        baca=open('yo.JPG','rb')
        tulis=open('hasil.JPG','wb')
        i=0
        start_time = time.time()
        while(i<=(os.path.getsize('yo.JPG')/16)):
            asd=getNextInput(baca)
            plain=toTable(asd)
            cipherKey=[0x2b,0x7e,0x15,0x16,0x28,0xae,0xd2,0xa6,0xab,0xf7,0x15,0x88,0x09,0xcf,0x4f,0x3c]
            cipher=enkripsi(plain,cipherKey)
            putNextInput(cipher,tulis)
            i+=1
        tulis.close()
```

and now i'm trying to using file with .JPG format it works but the JPG result cannont open and with warning message "don't support this file format". maybe someone know the proble please help. thank you

Comment: You are encrypting a JPEG, opening it and wonder that it is not JPEG anymore?

Comment: You need to decrypt the encrypted .JPG file to get it into the correct format.  Best not to save the encrypted version with a `.jpg` extension as that will cause confusion.  Instead try something like `.jpg.encrypt`.